# Makefile rules vs source and object files

Tags: gcc, compilation, makefile, gnu-make, object-files

I'm studying how 'make' works and I encountered a little oddity

Suppose I have a folder with only 'helloworld.c' and 'Makefile'

Makefile contains

```
helloworld: helloworld.o
    gcc -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

The output of 'make' in a bash console is

> cc    -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.c
>
> gcc -o helloworld helloworld.o

The rule "helloworld" depends on the file "helloworld.o" which is not present, hence make creates it (the first line in the output).

**But why?**

I would have expected it to fail, in absence of a "helloworld.o:" rule that tells it how to compile said file. Why does it run the first command out of its own will?

Thanks

Comment: You don't even need a makefile in this case as the implicit rules already cover a target that has a source file (with a known suffix) with the same stem, try deleting your makefile and just running `make helloworld`.

Comment: As Edgar answered. Try `make -r` (or `make --no-builtin-rules`) to disable the implicit rules, which theoretically should make throw the error you do expect. If make documentation throws you off, consider some alternatives to make (BSD make, cmake, scons, jam, etc). IME make documentation is huge and is still manages to be rather poor.

Comment: I usually use at least `make -Rr` to get rid of the implicit rules (you only need one of `r` or `R`, but I can never remember which). Not a fan of pattern rules me. (`--warn` is also terribly useful; shame there is no corresponding `--error`, I would really like that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is *implicit rules*.

From the GNU Make manual:

> Implicit rules tell make how to use customary techniques so that you
>   do not have to specify them in detail when you want to use them. For
>   example, there is an implicit rule for C compilation. File names
>   determine which implicit rules are run. For example, C compilation
>   typically takes a .c file and makes a .o file. So make applies the
>   implicit rule for C compilation when it sees this combination of file
>   name endings.

In other words, make knows how to build *helloworld.o* from *helloworld.c* even if you don't specify an appropriate rule.

To get more information on this subject you can follow [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), especially section 10, which is devoted to the usage of implicit rules.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right section of the manual (it's huge!).